# When should I use useEffect hook instead of event listeners?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, event-listener

Should `useEffect` hook be used when it can be simplified using an event listener?

For example, in the below snippet code I use event listener to change some state and later `useEffect` hook to react to that state change and do some other thing

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Foo() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // do any kind of business logic
  }, [isActive]);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="secondary"
        onClick={() => setIsActive(true)}
      >
        ACTIVATE
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="secondary"
        onClick={() => setIsActive(false)}
      >
        DEACTIVATE
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Should I move `useEffect` logic to the `onClick` listeners?

Comment: They would be doing different things — for example clicking the same button multiple times would not cause anything to happen, whereas moving the fetching logic to the `button` would cause it to fetch every click. Your question more depends what the the desired end result is!

Comment: you don't need, useEffect on the button click you can call an API set to state.

Comment: I know that I don't need `useEffect` for simple operations

I am just asking when is better to use `useEffect` or `event listeners`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general I think if you can handle something in event handler you should do that. React docs don't advise to overuse `useEffect`, and also they suggest it is more for cases when you want to synchronize with some external system. More below:

[Docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/keeping-components-pure#where-you-can-cause-side-effects):

> In React, side effects usually belong inside event handlers. Event
> handlers are functions that React runs when you perform some
> action—for example, when you click a button. Even though event
> handlers are defined inside your component, they don’t run during
> rendering! So event handlers don’t need to be pure.
>
> If you’ve exhausted all other options and can’t find the right event
> handler for your side effect, you can still attach it to your returned
> JSX with a useEffect call in your component. This tells React to
> execute it later, after rendering, when side effects are allowed.
> However, this approach should be your last resort.

[Docs](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#how-to-remove-unnecessary-effects) suggest to use `useEffect` it more in cases when you want to synchronize with some external system:

> You do need Effects to synchronize with external systems. For example,
> you can write an Effect that keeps a jQuery widget synchronized with
> the React state. You can also fetch data with Effects: for example,
> you can synchronize the search results with the current search query

For a more in depth look I suggest you look at the [docs](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `useEffect` for simple operations, `useEffect` will also call on the component mount that you have to handle.

```
export default function Foo() {
  const onClick = useCallback((isActive) => {
    // fetch some data
    // set that data to state
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" className="secondary" onClick={() => onClick(true)}>
        ACTIVATE
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="secondary"
        onClick={() => onClick(false)}
      >
        DEACTIVATE
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I know that I don't need `useEffect` for simple operations. 

I am just asking when is better to use `useEffect` or `event listeners`

Comment: In this case, useEffect does not help, `useEffect` is helpful when something is changing you want to observe that and something you want to trigger on mount/on unmount.

Answer (score 0):

UseEffect run once when the component does mounting.

You can have state that triger the useEffect .

Should You move `useEffect` logic to the `onClick` listeners?

That depend on you, if you need to `render` your app , so no.

onClick function need do to something that depend to the page logic.